# Identity Server 4 OIDC authorization_code flow multi tenancy

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, openid-connect

I'm facing an issue for authenticating my users on my IS4 server with an application (Blazor Server/WASM).
My IDSRV4 is located on the same app that the API to protect, and each client has it owns database (for users and business models).

To choose the good database, I use an header and have set up a interceptor on EF Core to choose database according to header value.

Everything works great, except authentication. I was using *resource_owner_password* flow with a JavaScript app (security breach, I know) which allows me to pass custom headers for each calls (calling /connect/token with my custom header).

Now, with the *authorization_code* flow, I cannot manage to pass the header to choose good tenant, meaning good database, which causes authentication to failed because token is validated on another database that the user is currently register to.

I can pass the tenant to choose database during login process (when posting login info on IDSRV4 side), and I've set up event on client side to add header on when sending back code for having back id_token, but I lost the capability to do that after my idp redirect user after login on /connect/authorize (it seems there no extension on IDSRV4 side for adding custom headers).

So my user post login data (with tenant infos), that I lost when redirecting to /connect/authorize, and I have no way to customize this. Is there any chance to do that ?

Merging all users in the same database is not an option.

Comment: as you use bearer token to access api, I think your best choice is to put the tenant into claim. otherwise your solution is not secure: your user logs in into any tenant, then changes the header and get/manipulate the data for any other tenant. nevertheless you can set any custom header on any MVC action such as login. nothing Identityserver-specific there. one easy way is to derive from `ActionFilterAttribute` implement your `OnResultExecuting` and apply the attribute to `AccountController`

Comment: Changing header tenant would result of 401 because token was generated against another database and user/token is not recognized. I've encounter this so many times during development when using Postman and forget to change tenant header with a token of another one. However, my issue is not to have a custom header on MVC action, but to redirect to client with this tenant info after /connect/authorize

Comment: You can still add any custom headers to any HttpResponse from your MVC app hosting Identityserver. Just add a middleware into the pipeline. I'll post an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can still add any custom headers to any `HttpResponse` from your MVC app hosting Identityserver.

```cs
// public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
app.UseCustomHeaders();

//CustomHeadersMiddleware.cs
public static class CustomHeadersMiddlewareExtensions
{
  public static IApplicationBuilder UseCustomHeaders(
    this IApplicationBuilder builder)
  {
    return builder.UseMiddleware<CustomHeadersMiddleware>();
  }
}

public class CustomHeadersMiddleware
{
  private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
  private readonly ILogger<CustomHeadersMiddleware> _logger;

  public CustomHeadersMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, 
    ILogger<CustomHeadersMiddleware> logger)
  {
    _next = next;
    _logger = logger;
  }

  public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
  {
    var watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();

    //To add Headers AFTER everything you need to do this
    context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
    {
      if (!context.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Response-Time-Milliseconds"))
                    context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Response-Time-Milliseconds",
                        new[] {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString()});

      return Task.FromResult(0);
    });

    await _next(context);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, it was what I try, without success. 
According to this : https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/18897890ce2cb020a71b836db030f3ed1ae57882/src/IdentityServer4/src/Endpoints/Results/AuthorizeResult.cs#L119 it seems that a html form is posted, that remove all my custom headers after authorize_code generation

Comment: I have a similar approach. However, identity server generates a custom response for authorize/callback endpoint, that creates an html form, which is written in response, and that post data on client callback uri on load (by Javascript, see link I posted before). I have currently no way of interfering in this operation to add custom headers while posting to clien callback uri... (response cannot be read and rewrite in middleware)

Comment: consider just trying it exact as is, ensure it works, then adjust up to your needs. forgot to mention: I added it to the pipeline on a very high position, just below `app.UseHealthChecks()` and a "last chance" error handling middleware.

Comment: regarding the "response cannot be read and rewrite in middleware" the trick is to use `context.Response.OnStarting(()={})` and register it on very early stage. only then it works

Comment: Event with removing all my custom code, headers are not retrievied, because the response that is produce is an html form, that is posted when response if flushed, so it loose my headers and I don't get them back on my client app (in signin-oidc call)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225031/discussion-between-cdie-and-d-f).

Comment: https://github.com/dfrunet/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI upgraded to net core 3.1; added custom headers

Answer (score 0):

This is old post but this is how I handled this case.
You can store the tenantId in localstorage before you call authorize method
and in the httpLoaderFactory get the tenantId from localstorage and set the customParamsCodeRequest of the OpenIdConfiguration. Unfortunately I wasn't able to pass the customParams when calling authorize() or checkAuth() method on the code flow, it is only possible with implicit flow.

Angular oidc example:

```
localStorage.setItem("tenantId", "my_tenant_id");
this.oidcSecurityService.authorize();
```

AppModule:

```
export const httpLoaderFactory = (http: HttpClient) => {
    let config$: Observable<OpenIdConfiguration> = new Observable((s) => {
        let tenantId = localStorage.getItem("tenantId") ?? "";
        let c: OpenIdConfiguration = {
            authority: "identityserver",
            redirectUrl: window.location.origin + "/",
            postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
            clientId: "aaa",
            scope: "openid profile api1",
            responseType: "code",
            silentRenew: true,
            useRefreshToken: true,
            logLevel: LogLevel.Debug,
            customParamsCodeRequest: { tenantId: tenantId },
        };
        return s.next(c);
    });
    return new StsConfigHttpLoader(config$);
};
```

AppModule Imports:

```
imports: [
        ...
        AuthModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: StsConfigLoader,
                useFactory: httpLoaderFactory,
                deps: [HttpClient],
            },
        }),
    ],
```